# How can I add a Hover Effect to an Image in an SVG Path?

Tags: html, css, svg, mousehover

I'm designing a radial menu using SVG paths:

[image: Home Network Landing Page Menu]

Each "sector" should have an image that changes when the mouse cursor is inside that sector.

I have tested using `:hover` styles on pretty much everything in my `.css` file, but I can't figure out a way to make the image change together with the sector when it becomes highlighted.

```
<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 83 83">

  <!-- Red light -->
  <image
    xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Srouge.png/80px-Srouge.png"
    width="83" height="83"
  ></image>

  <!-- Green light for hover, can't get it to work -->
  <!--
  <image
    xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Svert.png/80px-Svert.png"
    width="83" height="83"
  ></image>
  -->

</symbol>
```

Is there a way to switch to a different image when the SVG path gets highlighted without using JavaScript?

You can view the full code of my menu attempt here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tjdbkge5/

---

EDIT: Instead of replacing the image, fading it out with CSS filters would be fine, too. I just haven't managed to trigger these with the SVG path (they trigger only when the mouse is over the image itself).

Example:

```
symbol {
  overflow: visible;
  filter: grayscale(80%) brightness(25%);
  opacity: 0.25;
}

symbol:hover {
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, your problem here is that CSS can't "penetrate" the SVG element - to change stuff, this can be done with JS and classes. You could use your main element (#menu) of the svg to change the img, but is is then affected on hover of the whole SVG and not the specific part you want.

Comment: If the `<svg />` tag is used (versus `<img />` with an external `.svg` file), CSS can be used. For example, the rainbow colors come from CSS, also, the `.item:hover .sector, .item:focus .sector` line is currently responsible for highlighting sectors on mouse-over.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do it put two symbols in each sector.  One is initially visible, and the other is hidden.  Then when you hover over the sector, hide the first one and show the second.

```
<a class="item" ...>
  <path .. />
  <use xlink:href="#icon-1" ... />
  <use xlink:href="#icon-2" ... />
</a>
```

For hiding and showing, we use `opacity`:

```
.item use {
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.item use.hovered {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover use.unhovered {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover use.hovered {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Demo:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.item .sector {
    transition: all .1s linear;
    stroke: #111;
}

.item:hover .sector, .item:focus .sector {
    fill: #eee;
}

.item use {
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.item use.hovered {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover use.unhovered {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover use.hovered {
  opacity: 1;
}


#item-1 {
  fill: #a364d9;
}
/* Next: #40a4d8 */
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Home Network Portal Page">

    <title>Portal</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css"> -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="-252 -252 516 516"
      style="display:block; position:absolute; top:5%; left:5%; width:90%; height:90%;"
      id="menu"
    >
      <g id="symbolsContainer">
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!-- Red light -->
          <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Srouge.png/80px-Srouge.png" height="83" width="83"></image>
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">1</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Svert.png/80px-Svert.png" height="83" width="83"></image>
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">2</text>
        </symbol>
      </g>

      <g id="itemsContainer">

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-1"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 234.923155196477,-85.5050358314172
              A 250,250 0 0,1 234.923155196477,85.5050358314172
              L 117.461577598239,42.7525179157086
              A 125,125 0 0,0 117.461577598239,-42.7525179157086
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-1"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(90 0 0)"
            class="unhovered"
          ></use>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-2"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(90 0 0)"
            class="hovered"
          ></use>
        </a>

      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you've said NO javascript.

Have you considered using SVG instead of images? If your images are all like the traffic light, you may use SVG and in this case it may be possible using only CSS.

I'm using javascript for this. There is a use element to reuse an image. The xlink:href attribute of the use element changes on  mouseover and mouseout.

I've added an id to the path ("purple") but it can be done differently when you have all the images in place.

In CSS I've added `use{pointer-events:none}` I hope this is not interfering with your functionality.

```js
const XLINK_NS="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

purple.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{
  us.setAttributeNS(XLINK_NS,"xlink:href", "#green")
})

purple.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{
  us.setAttributeNS(XLINK_NS,"xlink:href", "#red")
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.item .sector {
    transition: all .1s linear;
    stroke: #111;
}

.item:hover .sector, .item:focus .sector {
    fill: #eee;
}

.menu-trigger {
    fill: #EA2A55;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-trigger:hover, .menu-trigger:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
}
symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}

#item-1 {
  fill: #a364d9;
}
#item-2 {
  fill: #ee6579;
}
#item-3 {
  fill: #db3937;
}
#item-4 {
  fill: #f66320;
}
#item-5 {
  fill: #f8a227;
}
#item-6 {
  fill: #fecc2f;
}
#item-7 {
  fill: #b2c224;
}
#item-8 {
  fill: #33beb7
}
/* Next: #40a4d8 */

use{pointer-events:none}
```

```html
 <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="-252 -252 516 516"
      style="display:block; position:absolute; top:5%; left:5%; width:90%; height:90%;"
      id="menu"
    >
   
   <defs>
     <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/Srouge.png/80px-Srouge.png" height="83" width="83" id="red"></image>
     
     <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Svert.png/80px-Svert.png" height="83" width="83" id="green"></image>
     
   </defs>
      <g id="symbolsContainer">
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
        <!-- Red light -->
        <use xlink:href="#red" id="us" />
        
        <!-- Green light for hover, can't get it to work -->
        <!--
        <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Svert.png/80px-Svert.png" height="83" width="83"></image>
        -->
        
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">1</text>
        </symbol>
        
        
        
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">2</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-3" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">3</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-4" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">4</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-5" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">5</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-6" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">6</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-7" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">7</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-8" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">8</text>
        </symbol>
      </g>

      <g id="itemsContainer">

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-1"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path id="purple"
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 234.923155196477,-85.5050358314172
              A 250,250 0 0,1 234.923155196477,85.5050358314172
              L 117.461577598239,42.7525179157086
              A 125,125 0 0,0 117.461577598239,-42.7525179157086
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-1"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(90 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-2"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 105.654565435175,-226.576946759163
              A 250,250 0 0,1 226.576946759163,-105.654565435175
              L 113.288473379581,-52.8272827175874
              A 125,125 0 0,0 52.8272827175875,-113.288473379581
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-2"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(45 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-3"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -85.5050358314171,-234.923155196477
              A 250,250 0 0,1 85.5050358314172,-234.923155196477
              L 42.7525179157086,-117.461577598239
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -42.7525179157086,-117.461577598239
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-3"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(0 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-4"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -226.576946759163,-105.654565435175
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -105.654565435175,-226.576946759163
              L -52.8272827175874,-113.288473379581
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -113.288473379581,-52.8272827175874
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-4"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(315 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-5"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -234.923155196477,85.5050358314172
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -234.923155196477,-85.5050358314172
              L -117.461577598239,-42.7525179157086
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -117.461577598239,42.7525179157086
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-5"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(270 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-6"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -105.654565435175,226.576946759163
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -226.576946759163,105.654565435175
              L -113.288473379581,52.8272827175874
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -52.8272827175874,113.288473379581
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-6"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(225 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-7"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 85.5050358314172,234.923155196477
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -85.5050358314172,234.923155196477
              L -42.7525179157086,117.461577598239
              A 125,125 0 0,0 42.7525179157086,117.461577598239
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-7"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(180 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-8"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 226.576946759163,105.654565435175
              A 250,250 0 0,1 105.654565435175,226.576946759163
              L 52.8272827175874,113.288473379581
              A 125,125 0 0,0 113.288473379581,52.8272827175874
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-8"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(135 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

Here is an other example where I'm using SVG instead of images:

To your CSS I'm adding 2 lines:

```css
use{pointer-events:none}
#purple:hover+use{fill:red}
```

Instead of the image I'm using an SVG symbol (Google's home icon) that I'm using with `<use>`and comes immediately after the `#purple` path.

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

#menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.item .sector {
    transition: all .1s linear;
    stroke: #111;
}

.item:hover .sector, .item:focus .sector {
    fill: #eee;
}

.menu-trigger {
    fill: #EA2A55;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-trigger:hover, .menu-trigger:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
}
symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}

#item-1 {
  fill: #a364d9;
}
#item-2 {
  fill: #ee6579;
}
#item-3 {
  fill: #db3937;
}
#item-4 {
  fill: #f66320;
}
#item-5 {
  fill: #f8a227;
}
#item-6 {
  fill: #fecc2f;
}
#item-7 {
  fill: #b2c224;
}
#item-8 {
  fill: #33beb7
}
/* Next: #40a4d8 */

use{pointer-events:none}
#purple:hover+use{fill:red}
```

```html
 <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="-252 -252 516 516"
      style="display:block; position:absolute; top:5%; left:5%; width:90%; height:90%;"
      id="menu"
    >
   
   <defs>
    <symbol id="home" viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>home</title>
    <path d='M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3l-10-9-10 9h3v8z'></path>
    <!--<path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>-->
    </symbol>
     
   </defs>
      <g id="symbolsContainer">
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
        <!-- Red light -->
        
        
        <!-- Green light for hover, can't get it to work -->
        <!--
        <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bc/Svert.png/80px-Svert.png" height="83" width="83"></image>
        -->
        
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">1</text>
        </symbol>
        
        
        
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">2</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-3" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">3</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-4" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">4</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-5" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">5</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-6" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">6</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-7" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">7</text>
        </symbol>
        <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-8" viewBox="0 0 83 83">
          <!--Replace the contents of this symbol with the content of your icon-->
          <rect fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
          <text fill="#222" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1.2em">8</text>
        </symbol>
      </g>

      <g id="itemsContainer">

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-1"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path id="purple"
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 234.923155196477,-85.5050358314172
              A 250,250 0 0,1 234.923155196477,85.5050358314172
              L 117.461577598239,42.7525179157086
              A 125,125 0 0,0 117.461577598239,-42.7525179157086
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          
         
          <!--<use 
            xlink:href="#icon-1"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(90 0 0)"
          ></use>-->
          
          <use id="test" xlink:href="#home" width="83" height="83" x="-41.5" y="-230.5" fill="gold" transform="rotate(90 0 0)" />
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-2"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 105.654565435175,-226.576946759163
              A 250,250 0 0,1 226.576946759163,-105.654565435175
              L 113.288473379581,-52.8272827175874
              A 125,125 0 0,0 52.8272827175875,-113.288473379581
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-2"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(45 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-3"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -85.5050358314171,-234.923155196477
              A 250,250 0 0,1 85.5050358314172,-234.923155196477
              L 42.7525179157086,-117.461577598239
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -42.7525179157086,-117.461577598239
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-3"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(0 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-4"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -226.576946759163,-105.654565435175
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -105.654565435175,-226.576946759163
              L -52.8272827175874,-113.288473379581
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -113.288473379581,-52.8272827175874
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-4"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(315 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-5"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -234.923155196477,85.5050358314172
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -234.923155196477,-85.5050358314172
              L -117.461577598239,-42.7525179157086
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -117.461577598239,42.7525179157086
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-5"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(270 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-6"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M -105.654565435175,226.576946759163
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -226.576946759163,105.654565435175
              L -113.288473379581,52.8272827175874
              A 125,125 0 0,0 -52.8272827175874,113.288473379581
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-6"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(225 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-7"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 85.5050358314172,234.923155196477
              A 250,250 0 0,1 -85.5050358314172,234.923155196477
              L -42.7525179157086,117.461577598239
              A 125,125 0 0,0 42.7525179157086,117.461577598239
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-7"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(180 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>

        <a
          class="item"
          id="item-8"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          xlink:href=" "
          xlink:title=" "
        >
          <path
            class="sector"
            d="
              M 226.576946759163,105.654565435175
              A 250,250 0 0,1 105.654565435175,226.576946759163
              L 52.8272827175874,113.288473379581
              A 125,125 0 0,0 113.288473379581,52.8272827175874
              Z
            "
          ></path>
          <use
            xlink:href="#icon-8"
            width="83" height="83"
            x="-41.5" y="-230.5"
            transform="rotate(135 0 0)"
          ></use>
        </a>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! While I'd like to avoid JavaScript, I haven't ruled it out completely. My images are logos of various PHP/Java/Python webapps, converting them to SVG would be difficult. How would SVG icons help in this regard?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In the second demo I'm using SVG instead of images, and I'm using only CSS to change the color. I hope this helps or at least can give you some ideas.